# How to deselect a row in angular js programatically in ng grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-grid and it allows multiple selections.

After doing a save operation, I want to deselect the selected rows.

I tried doing something like this.selectedItems = [].

However, when I do that, if I select a row in ng-grid later, it doesnt bind to this.selectedItems. 
Instead it just remains an empty array.

My question here is on save, I want to be able deselect selected row.After that, any rows I select should bind to this.selectedItems.

Following is what I have for Grid options.

Any ideas and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
this.$scope.gridOptions = {
      data: 'myData',
      enablePaging: true,
      showFooter: true,
      totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems',
      pagingOptions: this.$scope.pagingOptions,
      sortInfo: this.$scope.sortOptions,
      useExternalSorting: true,
      selectedItems: this.selectedItems,
      multiSelect: true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following is working for me:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GVdaSmVR36Xmg9WGpyLY?p=preview)

First you need store gridApi:

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
};
```

Then you can use:

```
$scope.unSelectAll = function(){
    $scope.gridApi.selection.clearSelectedRows();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i actually had faced the same issue and after looking at the code of ng-grid, i had arrived at below solution

```
$scope.gridOptions.$gridScope.toggleSelectAll(false, true);
```

i dont remember the details of the parameters now, sorry for that...

Answer (score 1):

1. `$scope.gridOptions.$gridScope.toggleSelectAll(false, false);` // note: false,false
2. `this.selectedItems.length =0`

both of them work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`this.selectedItems = []`

do

```
this.selectedItems.length =0
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me!!

for one item:

```
 var index = row.rowIndex; //selected row index
  vm.expenseDataGridOptions.selectItem( index , false)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use

```
$scope.gridOptions.selectAll(false);
```

This works for me.