# How to deselect / unselect row in ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am using  function like : `gridApi.selection.clearSelectedRows();`

But how can I deselect the row in  the following function event :

```
gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(row){};
```

The situation: I am open a popup and when I close the modalService I should unselect the last row I clicked.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Store last selected row object**

```
$scope.lastSelectedRow = {};
 $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
                $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
                gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(row){
                if(row.isSelected) { 
                 // always store pointer to last row only if it is selected
                 $scope.lastSelectedRow = row;
                   } 
                });
            }
```

**Now you can unselect that row when you close the modal Instance**

```
$scope.clearLastSelectedRow  = function() {
       $scope.gridApi.selection.unSelectRow($scope.lastSelectedRow.entity);
};
```

More details [here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.selection.api:PublicApi)

Answer (score 0):

did you forget to store the gridApi? should look like below:

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
};
```

see this related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24959659/how-to-deselect-a-row-in-angular-js-programatically-in-ng-grid)